# How to make app visible on main screen (when minimised)?

Tags: android, react-native

trying to implement an application.

I want to make my app visible on top of the main android view like in this picture:
[image]

At the bottom right we can see minimised application that still runs when opening other applications like facebook or chrome, etc...

How to achieve similar behavior in react native?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use some android specifics, unless there's a react-native module doing that for you.

If its your app you want seen on top, have a look at [Pcture in Picture API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture)

If that doesnt work you can use SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission to achive this, but this will likely [not work with Android 11 and 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions) going forward.

I'm not sure how the app you mentioned is doing that for a different app like YouTube.

Comment: I am very happy for your response.
Picture in Picture API seems the way to go.

Do not want to implement my app with something that will go obsolete in future.

Would this picture to picture API would support background audio mode when locking the screen?

Comment: That's a bit unrelated to PiP. You'll have to do the video and audio decode and playback in a background service with a WAKE_LOCK if you want that. See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer